# take several values in a multidimensional php array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [KrsId] => 2451493
            [Kode] => ST050
            [NamaMk] => MANAJEMEN STRATEGIK
            [NamaMkEn] => STRATEGIC MANAGEMENT
            [JmlSks] => 2
            [JmlPresensiKuliah] => 3
            [IsHadirMID] => 0
            [IsHadirUAS] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [KrsId] => 2451488
            [Kode] => ST087
            [NamaMk] => MANAJEMEN SUMBERDAYA IT
            [NamaMkEn] => IT RESOURCES MANAGEMENT
            [JmlSks] => 2
            [JmlPresensiKuliah] => 3
            [IsHadirMID] => 0
            [IsHadirUAS] => 0
        )
)
```

I want to take only a few keys, for example 3 like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NamaMk] => MANAJEMEN STRATEGIK
            [JmlSks] => 2
            [JmlPresensiKuliah] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [NamaMk] => MANAJEMEN SUMBERDAYA IT
            [JmlSks] => 2
            [JmlPresensiKuliah] => 3
        )
)
```

I have tried using array_column() but this can only take one key. is there the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:-

```
$newarr = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    $newarr[] = array(
                  'NamaMk' => $value['NamaMk'], 
                  'JmlSks' => $value['JmlSks'], 
                  'JmlPresensiKuliah' => $value['JmlPresensiKuliah']
           );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_map()` function

Here is code

```
   $newArr = array_map(function($value){
        return [ "NamaMk" =>$value['NamaMk'],
                 "JmlSks" => $value['JmlSks'],
                 "JmlPresensiKuliah" => $value['JmlPresensiKuliah']
               ];
    },$yourArr);
```